# How to retrieve facet's name in SimpleFacetedSearch?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
        SimpleFacetedSearch sfs = new SimpleFacetedSearch(_Reader, new string[] { "source", "category" });
        SimpleFacetedSearch.Hits hits = sfs.Search(query);

        foreach (SimpleFacetedSearch.HitsPerFacet hpg in hits.HitsPerFacet)
        {
            SimpleFacetedSearch.FacetName facetName = hpg.Name;
            for (int i = 0; i < facetName.Length; i++)
            {
                string part = facetName[i];
            }
        }
```

As far as I understand with this I am able to retrieve facet's values, but what is interesting for me is how could I possibly determine at which facet I am looking at, e.g. `source` or at `category` as in this example.